# weblogic 10.3.6 application all time availability

Tags: oracle, server, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, bea

I am using weblogic 10.3.6. I have a cluster configured and there are two managed servers MS-1 and MS-2. Now I have deployed my EAR into MS-1 and it is working fine. Now my requirement is while the application is running if somehow the MS-1 breaks down,all i want is that my application runs by switching to MS-2 ,that is I want my application to available all time, I am new to weblogic ,please help me .Detailed steps are needed

Comment: When you deploy a resource or an application to a WebLogic cluster, all cluster members (weblogic server instances) will serve the resource or the application. You should not start 1 server at a time. Fault tolerance can be achieved using a load balancer (Apache, HAProxy, etc...) in front of your cluster. It will load balance requests between all servers and will redirect http traffic when a server is down, to other cluster members.
Read this for complete information : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/core.1111/e10106/aa.htm#ASHIA977

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I am very new to this , let me ask for some more clarifications. You are saying about Load balancer like (Apache, HAProxy, etc...); does that means additional hardware? another thing while configuring a cluster in weblogic I have seen some parameter - Load balancer algorithm which uses values like round robin and etc. So can this parameter help me out in this aspect?  and what about session sharing concept in web logic

Comment: A load balancer is required beyong a weblogic cluster where you have deployed a web application. It will be in charge of load balancing http requests to the servers in the cluster. It can be a software like Apache Http Server or HAProxy, or a harware like F5 Big-IP. If you use a software load balancer you need to deploy it in front of the cluster, génerally in a dedicated host.

Comment: The load balancing algorithm you are talking about will be used by EJBs or RMI objects. In this situation, le load balancing (and fault tolerance) will be assumed by the client side of the EJB or RMI object. No http load balancer will be involved in this relation.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). One more help needed , if possible can you share with me some references or guidelines on how to configure this software load balancers like Apache HTTP server. That will be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic Server 10.3.6 documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/nav/wls.htm
WebLogic Server & Apache http server : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e16435/apache.htm#PLGWL395